# Pass javascript selection variable to rails controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, leaflet

I'm working on a rails (v.5.2.3) app that is supposed to provide data filter abilities for spatial data (model "measurements") based on (1) different variables and (2) a lasso selection on a map. Both of these filter options should be available in the same view ("welcome/index").

The relevant part of the controller for preparing and filtering the data:

```
# app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb
def index

    @selected_measurements = Measurement.where(
        "measurements_id IN (?) OR name = ?",
        params[:spatial_lasso_selection],      
        params[:query_site_name]
    ).all

    gon.selected_measurements = @selected_measurements.to_json
end
```

In the view I use form_tag for the filter variable definition (1):

```
# app/views/welcome/index.html.erb
<%= form_tag({controller: "welcome", action: "index"}, method: "get") do %>
    <%= label_tag(:query_site_name, "Site name:") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:query_site_name, (params[:query_site_name] or "")) %>
    <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

In the assets directory I have a javascript file that constructs a leaflet map (via leaflet-rails), adds the point data as markers and enables the [leaflet-lasso plugin](https://github.com/zakjan/leaflet-lasso) for (2) lasso selection on the map. This code is embedded in the welcome view to display the map there.

The lasso selection gives me a javascript array of measurement_ids. I want to send this array to my rails controller to filter the data and update the view (`params[:spatial_lasso_selection]`). I learned that I should do this with an ajax request, but I have difficulties implementing it. I don't understand how form_tag and raw javascript can be used together to make both (1) and (2) work seamlessly.

I figure the ajax call has to look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: '/welcome/index',
    data: { spatial_lasso_selection: JSON.stringify(lasso_selected_measurements) },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have problem also with ajax request. Instead I use input text value property to pass my javascript variable to the controller. Firstly just make simple form with hidden input property that have specific id in your `index.html`. Next create button that will send the variable to

```
<form id "myForm" action="/welcome/index">
  <input type="hidden" id="myVar" name="varParams">
</form>
<button id="btnSend">SEND</button>
```

Then, create javascript function to set the value of the input text with our required variable when the button is clicked. Just put below code in your `index.html`.

```
<script>
document.getElementById('btnSend').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.getElementById("myVar").value = "myValue";
  document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
});
</script>
```

Next, just retrieve the myVar params in your `welcome_controller.rb`.

```
  def index
    myVar = params[:varParams]
    # Do something with myVar variable  
  end
```

Comment: I did not try this solution as this answer was submitted long after the question was asked and I don't have a setup to test it any more. I decided to accept it nevertheless as it seems to answer the question well.

Comment: Many thank for accepting this answer. Hopefully this answer will be useful to someone else.